# Matching parenthesis content in PCRE without outermost parens

Tags: regex, pcre

I need to extract content of unbalanced paren construction. In manual for PCRE i found solution for matching balanced parens.

```
<\[ ( (?>[^(<\[|\]>)]+) | (?R) )* \]>
```

For my test

```
<[<[ab<[cd]>]><[ef]>
```

It extracts

```
0.0: <[ab<[cd]>]>
0.1: <[ef]>
```

But i want to extract same content without outermost parens:

```
0.0: ab<[cd]>
0.1: ef
```

Could anybody point a solution?

Comment: Please post a sample of what your desired extractions would look like.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from the look of your regex, the content inside the outermost enclosure (they're not parentheses in any normal usage of the term) is already being captured in a parenthesis group.  I don't know what context you're using the PCRE library in, but the extractions you want should be present in "match #1" (where the entire pattern match is match #0).  i.e. your data should already look like:

```
0.0: <[ab<[cd]>]>
0.1: <[ef]>
1.0: ab<[cd]>
1.1: ef
```

Comment: Target system is PHP 5.2. And for this regexp i recieve

    0.0: (<[ab<[cd]>]>)
    0.1: (<[ef]>)
    1.0: (<[cd]>)
    1.1: (ef)